# Why I am not able to make a connection to a sql server 2008 via sqlcinet in .net but with oledb I can?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a `Windows 2008 R2 x64` enterprise edition + `SQL Server 2008 R2` datacenter edition
from its local computer I can make connection to the `SQL` server with `sqlClient` in `C#`
and here is my connection string looks like :

```
using (sqlconnection cn = new sqlconnection("Data Source=myServerIPAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"))
{
    cn.open();  //I'll get error here from remote
    using (sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("sql",cn))
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

but with exact above code from a remote computer I'll get this error :

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period
elapsed prior to completion of the
operation or the server is not
responding.
```

but when I change above code to oledb  everything works fine.
respectively the connection string for `oledb` gonna change and this is my `oledb` connection string :

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data
Source=myserverIP;Password=password;User
ID=sa;Initial Catalog=catalog
```

*note*: I've tried [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) also but no difference.

Comment: Are you sure this code is working because this code has syntax errors like ')' is missing in using etc

Comment: yeah code is working , as I said its working on the local but not from any remote computer where as with oledb it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai,
   please set Connection Timeout attribute of your connection string .

Comment: as connectionstrings.com said there is no timeout attr exist in connection string for sql server 2008.
but anyhow I've done what you've told here and thanks it works but there is a bigger problem : it is slow as hell!!! where as oledb connection is too fast.
I've read somewhere that sqlclient is way faster than oledb but in reality it is totally reverse.
do you have any idea about it?
regards.

Comment: I think problem with Sql server .Create yourself another user with the correct priveledges of user ID sa.

Comment: I'm using "sa" in my connection string and sa has full privileges over my desired catalog I don't have any idea of how to make any further changes , can you advise?
thanks

Comment: You can create new user in windows authentication mode or SQL Server Authentication. 
First go to your database->security->New User

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2008 server strips out the password from the connection string.

You have to specifically assign the password to your connection `cn`:

```
using (sqlconnection cn = new sqlconnection("Data Source=myServerIPAddress;Initial       Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"))
{
    cn.password = "myPassword";
    cn.open();  //I'll get error here from remote
    using (sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("sql",cn))
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is TCP/IP an enabled connection protocol for the Sql-Server? You can check this with the Sql Server Configuration Manager under "Sql Server Network Configuration".

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled also.
even after connection is created retrieving data is damn slow.